# Unexpected end of file error doing apt-get install in docker build on mac m1 pro

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apple-m1, apt-get

Getting error while building a dockerfile on Mac M1 pro.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -yqq install gcc
```

error I am getting

```
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN apt-get -y upgrade                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [4/4] RUN apt-get -yqq install gcc                                                                                                                                                              37.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 > [4/4] RUN apt-get -yqq install gcc:                                                                                                                                                                          
#7 37.30 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libasan6_10.2.1-6_arm64.deb  500  reading HTTP response body: unexpected EOF [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]                                
#7 37.30 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libtsan0_10.2.1-6_arm64.deb  500  reading HTTP response body: unexpected EOF [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
#7 37.30 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -yqq install gcc]: exit code: 100
```

The same dockerfile work perfectly on intel based mac. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I tried to build it for amd64 platform as well. it gives the same error.
The only solution I came up with was to manually download the package and then install it using apt. This seems to work, but it is a cumbersome process as there are a lot of package which is giving me this issue.